# rethinkdb update nested array of object (adding fields values)

Tags: javascript, rethinkdb

```
{
"deviceUsageList": [

    {
    "deviceName":  "4d002142dc334200" ,
    "totalTimePerDevice": 174851
    } ,
    {
    "deviceName":  "TA1040BVVN" ,
    "totalTimePerDevice": 74717
    } ,
    {
    "deviceName":  "dc38b80d" ,
    "totalTimePerDevice": 98324
    }

  ] ,

    "totalTimeUsed": 347892 ,
    "userEmail": xyz@gmail.com, 

} 



  {
    "deviceUsageList": [

        {
        "deviceName":  "8270de41" ,
        "totalTimePerDevice": 220978
        }

    ] ,

        "totalTimeUsed": 220978 ,
        "userEmail": abc@gmail.com,

    }
```

above is my object structure, i need to update the "totalTimePerDevice" value by adding the current value + previous value.

Query used for this is

[query to update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVavg.png)

But its giving wrong result 
Printing the same totalTimePerDevice="r.row('totalTimePerDevice')+132" on deviceName "4d002142dc334200".

i need to add the current value of totalTimePerDevice that is 132 + 174851=finally(174983) should get.

Comment: Hi, could you post an example input and the exact desired output?

Comment: input is totalTimePerDevice=132 and desired output totalTimePerDevice="currentValue(132)+previousValue(174851)", for the device "4d002142dc334200" please check the update query for more details.